# Uploading using Watir in IE waits for input

Tags: ruby, windows, internet-explorer, watir

I've tried to set up a script to upload a file using Watir, based on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687293/how-to-upload-a-file-with-watir-and-ie)

It just hasn't worked.  It's still waiting for my input.  It does go to the correct directory (folder) in Windows, but it does not actually select my file.  Occasionally it will select the file automatically, but that's only after I've made a change to the input_elements.rb file, saved the change and left the file open.  If I close the file after making a change, my script waits for me to select a file and click "Open" before proceeding.

I don't have any spaces in my file path; it's set in the script to
`C:\\hudson\\workspace\\Watir_test\\test_harness.xml`.  If I change the path to `C:\\test_harness.xml`, the "choose file" window does not change directories to the C: directory; it waits for my input.
So there's definitely something it's not doing/calling.

I have modified the `input_elements.rb` file based on the suggestions in the linked page, including increasing the wait time to 5 seconds, and it still hasn't helped.

I'm running Windows XP, Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: it's english version of windows xp, right?

Comment: Oh...sorry, yes it is.  United States English, if that makes any difference.

Comment: More information: I changed my test script so that it created an entirely new directory / build and it should have tried to upload the file within that build.  It did not - it opened the popup window which immediately directed to the directory of the last _successful_ upload.  It has consistently done this - opened the popup window in the last successful upload, and not selecting anything.

Comment: Adding: I'll check any logfiles needed if someone can tell me where they are.  I'm not familiar with where the logs are in Windows.

Comment: Just confirmed; it is only in IE that this is occurring.  Firefox uploads the file just fine.  I'm using IE 7.