# Automating a File Upload with WATIR in Chrome on OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, google-chrome, watir, watir-webdriver

I am attempting to automate a file upload using WATIR.   I don't control the website code and the javascript is obfuscated os it has been frustrating to figure out.

I have tried to set the file_field , but the site is using javascript to do the post and I can't trigger the submission.   My best best is to mimic the user.

There is a drag and drop interface and clicking it opens a standard OSX file chooser dialog.  I haven't been able to figure out how to control this file chooser dialog from WATIR.  It looks like on IE there is a library called window_helper that allows you to do this.

[How to upload a file with watir and IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687293/how-to-upload-a-file-with-watir-and-ie)

I can't figure it out in Chrome.

Comment: Please share link to the page and the code that you have so far.

Comment: The page is the file upload box on Google Play.  We are trying to automate uploading an android APK.  I can't share a link because it is behind authentication.  We don't have any code yet, since this is the hardest part and haven't found support for the File Chooser Dialog.

Comment: can you give a path to such a page? or does someone have to be registered as a developer to get to the upload page?

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable way I've found to interact with file upload fields on OSX is to use:

```
$browser.file_field(:id, //).set("filepath\/...\/file.png")
```

Unfortunately, it will only select the file, it will not close the dialog.

However, as Željko says its difficult to help without any point of reference for what the page looks like/what your code is doing.

Comment: So I am guessing that it is true.  There is no way with WATIR to interact with a file chooser dialog in chrome on Mac OSX.

Comment: those chooser dialogs are most likely coming from the OS, and are not really present 'inside' the browser.   If you are testing that sort of thing you'll need some other scripting tool to fill in the dialog.  but also ask yourself, is it your job to test the OS.. all such dialogs typically do is return a filespec (path+name) which you can often input directly, or perhaps set via executing some javascript directly.

Answer (score 3):

If your only choice is to automate the operating system's file selection control, then you will perhaps have to use a different tool at that point in your script.

One option to consider would be [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) which works visually.  I've not tried using it on a mac, so I have no idea how well it is suited for that platform, but it works well on a PC.

Another possible would be the gem [AXElements](http://rubygems.org/gems/AXElements), which I've not used but appears promising

Comment: Thank you Chuck, for AXElements.. managed to get a work around with file upload dialog for Chrome in OS X..

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older question, but I just recently had to handle the FileUpload sheet on OSX for our automated suites at work so thought I'd post this as a resource for people.  We actually do use Sikuli for certain things like was mentioned previously, but try to use it as a last resort, since it requires visual recognition. (although agree that it works pretty well)

Instead, I used a couple Applescript handlers.  Our needs are different than the poster's, so normally these aren't contained in the same script like below.  I just put them in a script for the convenience of anyone that wanted to grab the code.  Just use whatever tool you want to invoke the File Upload sheet, and run the code below like so from terminal:

osascript /Path/To/The/Saved/Script.scpt /Path/To/MyUploadFile.txt Firefox Open

So as you can see, it requires 3 parameters.  The path to the file to upload, the name of the browser, and which button you want clicked in the File Upload sheet.  Of course you could just hard code those values if so desired.  We actually had a need to click Cancel occasionally which is why it's like that.

```
on run argv
if count of argv is not equal to 3 then
    log "You must pass 3 arguments to this script. The path to the file to upload, the browser name and finally the button to click."
    quit
end if

set theFileToUploadPath to item 1 of argv
set theBrowserName to item 2 of argv
set theButtonToClick to item 3 of argv 

goToFolder(theFileToUploadPath)
delay 1
clickFileUploadButton(theBrowserName, theButtonToClick)
end run

on goToFolder(folderPath)
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
    delay 1
    keystroke folderPath
    delay 1
    key code 76
end tell
end goToFolder

on clickFileUploadButton(browserName, buttonToClick)
tell application "System Events"

    try
        tell process browserName
            activate
            if buttonToClick is equal to "Cancel" then
                click button "Cancel" of window "File Upload"
            else if buttonToClick is equal to "Open" then
                click button "Open" of window "File Upload"
            else
                log "Incorrect button passed to handler"
            end if
        end tell
    on error
        log "Unable to close File Upload window for browser: " & browserName
    end try

end tell
end clickFileUploadButton
```

Hope this helps someone at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You could use RAutomation to do that, This can access the default file chooser dialog

Example:

```
window = RAutomation::Window.new :title => windowTitle
window.text_field(:class =>"Edit").set(file_name)
window.button(:value => "&Open").click
```

Comment: Last I read, RAutomation was only for Windows. The question is about OS X.

Comment: Yup, it's for windows only at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

potentially after the field has been populated, there could be some client side code that is waiting for an event like onChange to fire..  you might have to try firing the event at the control after changing setting the filename